# How to achieve a particular simplification level of an expression in wxMaxima?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have the following input in wxMaxima:

```
BC:(sqrt((L^2)-((R^2)*sin(α)^2))+R*cos(α))*tg(α)$
AC:(sqrt((L^2)-((R^2)*sin(α)^2)))/cos(α)$
v_B:ω*R*(BC/AC)$
v_B;
```

I get the desired result but it's in a quite complicated form. I would like to simplify it to this:

[image]

I tried various options from the Simplify menu (especially Trigonometric Simplification) but none of them gave me such a result. Is there a way to perform this kind of simplification in wxMaxima?

Comment: If you've already tried the menu, that probably covers the functions that are relevant (trigsimp, etc -- `?? trig` will show some documentation). The one thing I see is that Maxima won't recognize `tg` -- I guess you must mean `tan` there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I thought that "tg" is recognized by Maxima. Unfortunately, after changing it to "tan" it still doesn't simplify the expression as desired. Maybe this form of simplification is not handled by Maxima.

Comment: Maxima embodies some heuristics for simplifying expressions, and unfortunately the kind of cleverness exercised pretty easily by humans is not so easily automated ... it's often pretty easy to grasp possible simplifications and then work towards them by hand, and difficult to do it automatically. That said, there are quite a few simplification functions in Maxima -- maybe some combination of them  could yield the desired result.